# Proper work flow to move manholes and pipes to surveyed location

Tags: qgis, gps

I would like to know how to accomplish the following task using QGIS.

I have an existing point shapefile representing sanitary sewer manholes and an existing polyline shapefile representing sanitary sewer pipes.  All pipes are connected (snapped) to a manhole and all manholes are approximate location.  Recently a survey crew collected GPS points (4,000) for some of the manholes.  I need to move all manholes and pipes to their correct location.  How can this easily be done using QGIS?

Comment: Is there a join field between the two tables e.g manholoe id

Answer (score 2):

Plot the new correct manhole locations on one layer and the old manholes on another. 
Use mmqgis plugin and the hub feature to give each of the new manholes an attribute of the old, based on the presumption that nearest proximity is a suitable relationship.

After that step I am guessing, but I suggest location at a linear referencing system which can be achieved in QGIs with a Postgis db. 
Or ytou may be able to do more with the hub tools and assign a common attribute to the pipe layer.

ciao

Comment: how did you go, was my answer in any way helpful?